# Deletar apenas checkbox selecionados PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Estou com um sistema que fiz (não entendo muito de PHP) funcionava perfeitamente porém após trocar de servidor parou de funcionar a função de deletar apenas os checkbox selecionados, ele simplesmente deleta tudo.

Eu busco todos eles de banco de dados e mando exibir apenas os 4 primeiros ID (normalmente são gravados com erro no Banco - XML com problema que não vem de mim).

Segue parte do código.

```
<form method="post" action="limpar_selecionados.php">
<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM loja WHERE categoria = 'NOTEBOOK' ORDER  BY nome ASC  LIMIT 4");
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
if($total > 0) {
do {
?>

<p> <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?=$linha['id']?>"   style="display:block;"/> </p>

<?php
    }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
}
?>

<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM loja WHERE categoria = 'Smartphone' ORDER  BY nome ASC  LIMIT 4");
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
if($total > 0) {
do {
?>

<p> <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?=$linha['id']?>"   style="display:block;"/> </p>

<?php
    }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Excluir Selecionados">

</form>
```

Limpar_selecionados.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); 
    if(isset($_POST['chk'])){
            $excluir = $_POST['chk'];

            foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $item) {
            $sql_deleta = "DELETE FROM `loja` WHERE `id` = '$item'";
            mysql_query($sql_deleta);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Só com esse código não tem como explicar esse comportamento.
Mesmo que *short_tags* esteja desativado ele não apagaria todos os registros. Deve ser outra coisa.
Tente adicionar no inicio dos scripts o código `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

Porque não organizas as `id` numa única variável, e depois executas como uma única consulta ? 
Outra coisa, é o facto de estares a passar o indentificador na atributo `value`, é desnecessário quando já tens esse mesmo valor na atributo`name`.

<del>Para ser sincero, não lembro exatamente, e não sei se, é esta a linha de pensamento correta, mas, posso afirmar que é incorreto assinar valores que não sejam `true` ou `false` ou equivalente às checkboxes. Alguém para me corrigir se eu estiver errado.</del>

De:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?=$linha['id']?>"/>
```

Para:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[<?=$linha['id']?>]"/>
```

Nesta parte do script, poderias simplesmente fazer:

```
if(isset($_POST['chk'])){
  $excluir = $_POST['chk'];

  foreach ($excluir as $item) {
          $sql_deleta = "DELETE FROM `loja` WHERE `id` = $item";
          mysql_query($sql_deleta);
}
}
```

Não sei se isto é uma função personalizada, criada por ti mesmo, ou se é apenas a velha *extensão* de conexão *MySQL*, porque se for, recomendo que comeces a usar *MySQLi* ou *PDO*.

```
mysql_query($sql_deleta);
```

Abaixo um exemplo de como executar as consultas, como uma única, usando a  cláusula `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM tabela_ WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3, idn...)
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
/* CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS exemplo; 
 * CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exemplo (
 * id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 * titulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 * PRIMARY KEY(id),
 * UNIQUE KEY(titulo));
 * INSERT INTO exemplo (titulo) VALUES ('primeiro'),('segundo'),
 * ('terceiro'),('quarto'),('quinto'),('sexto'),('setimo'),('oitavo')
 * ,('nono'),('decimo');
 */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "exemplo");

if(!$mysqli) die ("Erro: " . $mysqli->connect_errno());
$consulta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exemplo ORDER BY id ASC");

if($consulta){
 echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">";
 while($linha = $consulta->fetch_object()){
  echo "<article style=\"display:block;\">" . $linha->titulo . "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"item[{$linha->id}]\"></article>";
 }
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"apagar\" value=\"apagar\">";
 echo "</form>";
} else {
 die("Erro");
}


if(isset($_POST["apagar"])){
  $ids = "";
 foreach($_POST['item'] as $id=>$val){
  $ids .= $id . ',';
 }
 $ids = substr($ids, 0, -1);
 $apagar = "DELETE FROM exemplo WHERE id IN({$ids})";
 if($mysqli->query($apagar)){
  header("Location: exemplo.php");
  exit();
 } else {
  die("Erro: ". $mysqli->error);
 }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já verificou se a variável $item está com os valores corretos? e se o SQL de DELETE está correto?

Eu também percebi que você cria a variável `$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);` e depois cria ela novamente no `do {} while {}`, não sei se isso atrapalha em algo, não fiz testes, mas não sei se ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Por ter ocorrido após troca de servidor, provavelmente está relacionado ao PHP do seu novo servidor.

1. Se outros erros se apresentam, pode ser que a versão do PHP do novo servidor seja mais recente e funções utilizadas em seu código estejam depreciadas.
2. Em seu atual código, você utiliza short tag `<?=$linha['id']?>` short tag está habilitado em seu atual servidor? Caso não, será que seu `value="<?=$linha['id']?>"` não está retornando vazio por este motivo?

Não fiz testes, sugiro que faça estes testes para eliminar estas possibilidades.

Answer (score 0):

Use esse e com certeza irá funcionar:

```
<form method="post" action="limpar_selecionados.php">

<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loja WHERE categoria = 'NOTEBOOK' ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 4");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="'.$linha['id'].'" style="display:block"></p>';
    }
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loja WHERE categoria = 'Smartphone' ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 4");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="'.$linha['id'].'" style="display:block"></p>';
    }
}

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Excluir Selecionados">

</form>
```

Depois para deletar

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['chk'])){

    $chk = $_POST['chk'];

    foreach($chk as $item){

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM loja WHERE id = '".$item."'")
    }
}
?>
```

**Algumas observações**

A Função `mysql_` foi descontinuada, então recomendo que use `mysqli`.

Nunca usei a função `do while`, mas recomendo fazer sempre da maneira que eu fiz no código: Use somente a função `while()`

Não sei o seu conhecimento com PHP, mas você iria poupar código e processamento utilizando `funções` (function) no PHP, assim o código iria ficar mais limpo e mais rápido.

Utilize sempre a tag `<?php` . Quando você faz a migração para outro servidor, talvez a **short tag** não esteja ativa, para não ter dor de cabeça use sempre `<?php` :)