# Pegar valores de checkbox num array

Tags: php, mysql

Como consigo pegar o valor do checkbox no código abaixo?

É uma lista de presença e esse código eu modifiquei para um que uso um pouco diferente e desse jeito que está eu não sei como pegar os valores dos checkboxes marcados para poder em cada nome na tabela lançar a data em cada nome.

Tipo eu trago os nomes da tabela e os que estiverem presentes eu marco o checkbox e, quando salvar, a data vai ser escrita em cada nome que estiver marcado.

Segue o código:

```html
<table width="500" border="0"  bordercolor="#B9B3B3" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
              <?php
    
  $getfamilia = "SELECT * FROM $tabela";
  $getfamiliaquery = $mysqli->query($getfamilia);
  while($getfamilialine = mysqli_fetch_array($getfamiliaquery)) 
  { 
   $fn1="Em Andamento";
   $familia = $getfamilialine['nome'];
   $familia_id = $getfamilialine['id'];
   $fn=$getfamilialine['finalizado'];
   if(strcasecmp($fn, $fn1) == 0)
   {
   echo "
   <tr>
     <td width='250' align='center'>$familia </td>
     <td width='250'  align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='op'></td>
     
     </tr>
   ";
   }
  }
  
  echo "</table>"; /*fecha a tabela apos termino de impressão das linhas*/
print_r($mysqli->error);
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
 echo"Falha na conexao";
}

else
{
 
}
 ?>
    <br>
     <input type="submit" value="SALVAR" />
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Kelly, tentou passar o valor do ID no input: `<input type='checkbox' value='$familia_id' name='op'>`

Comment: tive essa ideia mas n cheguei a fazer pois ia pesquisar se podia fazer isso no value do checkbox vou ver aki

Comment: tentei pegar pelo id mas da erro na linha do update pq o id e um array. fiz isso aki mas n sei se ta certo.
<?php
$nome=$_POST['familia'];
$data=$_POST['date'];
$id=$_POST['familia_id'];
$tabela=$_SESSION['tabela'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['op']))
{
 $item= $_REQUEST['op'];

      
    $sql= $mysqli->query("UPDATE $tabela SET d1 = '$data' WHERE id = $item");
 
  print_r($mysqli->error);


}
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
    echo"Falha na conexao";
    }

   else
    {
 
    echo"<script> alert('Cadastro Efetuado com Sucesso!')</script>";
    echo "<script>redirectpage()</script>";
    }



?>

Comment: Kelly, postarei uma resposta.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92898/deletar-apenas-checkbox-selecionados-php/92917#92917

Comment: coloquei o codigo respondendo minha pegunta.... na tabela eu tenho as colunas d1 a d7 na qual tem q ir a data da presença de quem estiver presente. andei mexendo mas so entra no for. n entra em nenhum if. se a quantidade for igual a quantidade x insere a data na coluna correta

Answer (score 1):

Você deve colocar nome do Checkbox com []
Exemplo:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='op[]'>
```

e para pegar os dados, já criada a array, basta você dar

```
implode(',', $_POST['op']);
```

Caso queira saber mais, veja:
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 1):

Kelly, apenas não passei os valores para as variáveis `$familia` e `$familia_id`, fiz direto, mas fique à vontade.

O conceito é exatamente aquele que comentamos, a mágica está em  `value='".$getfamiliaquery["id"]."' name='op[]'` **value** armazena o id da família no loop (while), e **name** armazena a cada loop montando índices que será resgatado via POST assim: `$_POST['op'][0]`, `$_POST['op'][1]`, `$_POST['op'][2]`, e assim por diante.

```
<form action="" method="POST">    
    <table width="500" border="0"  bordercolor="#B9B3B3" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
            <?php

            $getfamilia = "SELECT * FROM $tabela";
            $getfamiliaquery = $mysqli->query($getfamilia);

            while($getfamilialine = mysqli_fetch_array($getfamiliaquery)) {
                if($getfamilialine["finalizado"] == "Em Andamento") {
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td width='250' align='center'>".$getfamilialine["nome"]."</td>
                            <td width='250' align='center'><input type='checkbox' value='".$getfamilialine["id"]."' name='op[]'></td>
                        </tr>";
                }
            }

            echo "</table>";
            ?>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="salvar_ok" value="SALVAR" />
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <?php
        // Aqui imprime o resultado retornado via POST
        if($_POST["salvar_ok"]) { // Se clicar no botão SALVAR executa o bloco abaixo
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["op"]); $i++) { // Loop enquanto houver conteúdo na array
                echo $_POST["op"][$i]."<br />"; // $_POST["op"][0], $_POST["op"][1], $_POST["op"][2], $_POST["op"][3]........ 
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: essa parte aki
 <td width='250' align='center'>".$getfamiliaquery["nome"]."</td>
                            <td width='250' align='center'><input type='checkbox' value='".$getfamiliaquery["id"]."' name='op[]'></td>
                        </tr>";

tive q tirar do jeito q vc fez e deixar do meu jeito pq assim nao apareceu o nome e o chekbox.

o que mostra no for eu joguei em outra pagina q é a q executa tudo o cadastro no banco e tals...

Comment: troquei e nao ta cadastrando no banco o pq eu nao sei. nao consegui testa no meu pc pelo localhost nao sei mas a pagina n abre direito pra mim. joguei em um servidor q é onde eu to pondo o site porem fala q cadastra mas quando puxo os dados nao tem nada porem eu nao to conseguindo acessa o servidor pra ver a minha tabela.... mas vou ir tentando aki qualquer coisa eu posto

Comment: Perdão Kelly, como tive que simular seu banco de dados para testar o código, inverti as variáveis rsrsrs. Corrigi o código na resposta. Desculpe.

Comment: eu nao estou conseguindo inserir os dados no banco de dados pelo for. meu cadastro chama um a outra pagina q é a q faz a inserção no banco. ele entra no for mas nao entra nas condições pra compara e fazer a inserção mas se eu ponho um echo ele mostra o q ta na variavel.

Comment: Consegue adicionar à sua resposta o conteúdo do código da outra página que faz o insert/update no banco de dados? Aí ficará mais fácil lhe auxiliar.

Comment: @KellyCris vi o restante do código que postou. Agora acredito que eu já não esteja entendo o objetivo. O que pude compreender é que primeiramente o form (checkbox) é listado a partir de uma consulta SQL em seu BD, portanto o que entendi que quer fazer é apenas um UPDATE no status, tipo de "Em Andamento" para "Finalizado", não seria isso?

Comment: seria o termino do tratamento mas eu ja resolvi o problema de cadastro ja esta funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de mais nada, seu código precisa de alguns ajustes, vou reformatá-lo abaixo. Para você pegar uma coleção através de um método post, você precisa tratar seus inputs como array e capturá-los da mesma forma, para fazer isso, formatei seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<pre>Falha na conexão:\n";
       print_r($mysqli->error);
    echo '</pre>'; die();
}

if ($_POST) {
  if (count($_POST['op'])) {
       foreach ($_POST['op'] as $key => $selecionado) {
          $familia_id = $_POST['familia_id'][$key];
          $familia    = $_POST['familia'][$key];
          $status     = $_POST['status'][$key]
          $addFamily  = "INSERT INTO $tabela (id, nome, finalizado)
                         VALUES ('$familia_id','$familia','$status')";
          $addFamilyQueryByStatus = $mysqli->query($addFamily);
      }
  }
  echo "<p>Salvamento processado com sucesso!</p>";
 die();
}

$getfamilia = "SELECT * FROM $tabela where finalizado = 'Em Andamento'";
$getfamiliaquery = $mysqli->query($getfamilia);

 ?> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" name="salvar">
<table width="500" border="0" bordercolor="#B9B3B3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if ($getfamiliaquery) {
            while ($getfamilialine = mysqli_fetch_array($getfamiliaquery)) { 
               $fn1        = "Em Andamento";
               $familia    = $getfamilialine['nome'];
               $familia_id = $getfamilialine['id'];
               $fn         = $getfamilialine['finalizado'];

                echo "
                 <tr>
                    <td width=\"250\" align=\"center\">{$familia}</td>
                    <td width=\"250\" align=\"center\">
                      <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"op[]\" value="1">
                      <input type=\"hidden\" value="{$fn}" name=\"status[]\">
                      <input type=\"hidden\" value="{$familia}" name=\"familia[]\">
                      <input type=\"hidden\" value="{$familia_id}" name=\"familia_id[]\">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ";
            } //fim do loop
        } else {
          echo "<p>Não há dados em andamento para serem processados.</p>";
        }
       //ob: você já fechou a tabela logo abaixo.
    ?>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="float:right">
          <input type="submit" value="SALVAR" />
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

> **Uma observação:** eu refatoraria sua tabela trocando o nome de "finalizado" para "status".

Answer (score 1):

o codigo q ta na outra pagina

```html
<?php
$nome=$_POST['familia'];
$data=$_POST['date'];
$id=$_POST['familia_id'];
$tabela=$_SESSION['tabela'];
$qtd=$_SESSION['qtd'];


if($_POST["salvar_ok"]) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["op"]); $i++) 
   
   {
               echo"$data";
      echo"$qtd";
      
      
      
      
      if($qtd=="NULL")
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d1) VALUES('$data')");
      
      echo"$data";
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      
      if($qtd=='1')
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d2) VALUES('$data')");
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      if($qtd=='2')
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d3) VALUES('$data')");
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      if($qtd=='3')
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d4) VALUES('$data')");
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      if($qtd=='4')
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d5) VALUES('$data')");
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      if($qtd=='5')
      
      {
       
      
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d6) VALUES('$data')");
 
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      if($qtd=='6')
      
      {
       
      $fn="sim";
      $sql= $mysqli->query(" INSERT IGNORE INTO $tabela (d7, finalizado) VALUES('$data', '$fn')");
    
         print_r($mysqli->error);
      
      }
      
      
            }
        }

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
    echo"Falha na conexao";
    }

   else
    {
 
    
    }



print '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
print '</pre>';

?>
```